# -d, -c, -r, ? What is the correct command to use in parameters to load an odoo configuration file into Run/Debug Configuration in Pycharm?

Tags: python, configuration, pycharm, odoo

Hellow every one I have been searched in other forums and I couldn't find a good definition of this situation
[Screenshot from Pycharm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzAaB.jpg)

I dont know what is the correct command to use in parameters to load an odoo configuration file into Run/Debug Configuration in Pycharm. I see in some examples people use ***`-d file.config`*** or ***`-c file.config`*** or ***`-r file.config`*** and I would like a definition of each command to define its correct use. Pls

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It is detailed in the [Command-line interface (CLI)](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/reference/cli.html#command-line-interface-cli) documentation

Answer (score 2):

`odoo-bin --help` gives quite detailed documentation of all command line parameters. Here is some extract:

```
[andrei@stealth2]$ odoo-bin --help
Usage: odoo-bin [options]

Options:
  --version             show program's version number and exit
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit

  Common options:
    -c CONFIG, --config=CONFIG
                        specify alternate config fileRequires

  Database related options:
    -d DB_NAME, --database=DB_NAME
                        specify the database name
    -r DB_USER, --db_user=DB_USER
                        specify the database user name
```

You can see here what the right option is :)